# Gremlin-Server Add Vertex with Multiple Properties (Titan 1.0.0)

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

I'm creating a Titan graph (backed by Dynamodb); I'm using Titan 1.0.0 and running Gremlin-Server 3 (on TinkerPop3).

I'm trying to add a vertex to my graph with a label and multiple properties in a single line.  I'm able to add a vertex with a label and a single property, and I can add multiple properties to a vertex after it has been created, but it seems that I can't do it all at once.

For testing I'm running commands in the gremlin shell, but the end use case is interacting with it via REST api (which is already working fine).

As a note, I'm rolling back after each of these transactions so I have a clean slate.

Here is how I'm initiating my session:

```
gremlin> graph = TitanFactory.open('conf/gremlin-server/dynamodb.properties')
==>standardtitangraph[com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.DynamoDBStoreManager:[127.0.0.1]]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[standardtitangraph[com.amazon.titan.diskstorage.dynamodb.DynamoDBStoreManager:[127.0.0.1]], standard]
```

I can create a vertex with a label and a single property like this:

```
gremlin> graph.addVertex('date_of_birth').property('date_of_birth','1949-01-01')
==>vp[date_of_birth->1949-01-01]
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('date_of_birth').has('date_of_birth','1949-01-01').valueMap()
==>[date_of_birth:[1949-01-01]]
```

I can also create a vertex and then append many properties afterward with a traversal starting at the vertex I just created:

```
gremlin> v1 = graph.addVertex('date_of_birth')
==>v[409608296]
gremlin> g.V(v1).property('date_of_birth','1949-01-01').property('year_of_birth',1949).property('date_of_birth','1949-01-01').property('day_of_birth',1).property('age',67).property('month_of_birth',1)
==>v[409608296]
gremlin> g.V(v1).valueMap()
==>[day_of_birth:[1], date_of_birth:[1949-01-01], month_of_birth:[1], age:[67], year_of_birth:[1949]]
```

This is all well and good, but I'm trying to avoid making 2 calls to achieve this result, so **I'd like to create the vertex with all of these properties at once**.  Essentially, I want to be able to do something like the following, but it fails with more than 1 `.property()`:

```
gremlin> graph.addVertex('date_of_birth').property('date_of_birth','1949-01-01').property('year_of_birth',1949).property('date_of_birth','1949-01-01').property('day_of_birth',1).property('age',67).property('month_of_birth',1)
No signature of method: com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.relations.SimpleTitanProperty.property() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [date_of_birth, 1949-01-01]
```

I've also tried using 1 `.property()` with multiple properties (along with all other syntax variations I could think of), but it only seems to catch the first one:

```
gremlin> graph.addVertex('date_of_birth').property('date_of_birth','1949-01-01','year_of_birth',1949,'date_of_birth','1949-01-01','day_of_birth',1,'age',67,'month_of_birth',1)
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('date_of_birth').has('date_of_birth','1949-01-01').valueMap()
==>[date_of_birth:[1949-01-01]]
```

I've looked through all of the documentation I can get my hands on from all sources I can find and I can't find anything on this "all at once" method.  Has anyone done this before or know how it could be done?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As described in [Chapter 3 Getting Started](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/getting-started.html) of the Titan docs, the [`GraphOfTheGodsFactory.java`](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/blob/1.0.0/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/example/GraphOfTheGodsFactory.java#L94) source code shows how to add a vertex with a label and multiple properties.

```
saturn = graph.addVertex(T.label, "titan", "name", "saturn", "age", 10000);
```

The method [`addVertex(Object... keyValues)`](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.0.1-incubating/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/structure/Graph.html#addVertex-java.lang.Object...-) ultimately comes from Graph interface defined by Apache TinkerPop. Titan 1.0.0 uses TinkerPop 3.0.1, and you can find more [documentation](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.0.1-incubating/#addvertex-step) on the `addVertex` step (and many other steps) in the TinkerPop docs.

Comment: ah!  That was it!  One thing that eluded me is the T object.  And now that you pointed it out, it's right smack in the middle of that doc *palm => face*.  Thanks for the quick answer, saved me a lot of frustration!