# add/update vertex and add/update multiple but an unknown number of properties to a vertex using gremlin

Tags: java, gremlin, janusgraph

I'm trying to add/update vertex and unknown number of properties using gremlin in java to janusgraph.

found an answer to add vertex here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56605921 couldnt convert this to work for add/update vertex.

i'm currently using this solution

```
g.V().has("vertexname", vertexname).fold().coalesce(__.unfold(), __.addV(label)).property("property1", property1value).property("property2", property2value).next();
```

However this doesnt work with unknown number of properties.

Is there a way i can combine the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56605921 with what i'm using to work for add/update vertex with unknown number of properties?

Comment: What do you mean by "an unknown number of properties"? Do you mean that the number isn't known when writing the program but is known at runtime?

Comment: we have different vertex labels. Properties of vertex are different for diferent label. i could make sepeate functions for add/update each vertex of label. however https://stackoverflow.com/a/56605921  is an interesting solution to inject maps to gremlin and make it work for dynamic collections.

Comment: hi were you able to find a solution for above problem ? @Sreerag