# Multiple properties of unknown number gremlin query

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, janusgraph, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

I am trying to add multiple properties to a gremlin vertex. Every time i have different number of properties and different properties as well so I need to make the query dynamic based on a Map to create or update the properties. I found this [gremlin python - add multiple but an unknown number of properties to a vertex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56602987/gremlin-python-add-multiple-but-an-unknown-number-of-properties-to-a-vertex) and tried to do the same with the difference that i instantiate a jansugraph but i get an error. Any ideas will be more than welcome.

The below are written in gremlin console directly, then i will translate it to java code.

```
graph =JanusGraphFactory.open("conf/test.properties")
g = graph.traversal()
test = [["testKey":"testValue"]]
g.inject(test).unfold().as("test")
 .V(20704).as("v").sideEffect(select("test"))
 .unfold().as("kv").select("v")
.property(select("kv").by(Column.keys),select("kv").by(Column.values)).iterate()
```

and the error i get is

```
The provided object does not have accessible keys: class org.janusgraph.graphdb.vertices.CacheVertex
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
Display stack trace? [yN]y
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The provided object does not have accessible keys: class org.janusgraph.graphdb.vertices.CacheVertex
```

Any ideas what i am doing wrong, i cannot find what to use for keys and values regarding Janus

Comment: I think you closed the `sideEffect` too soon.  The rest of the query until `iterate()` should be inside the `sideEffect` I believe.

Comment: oh thanks my bad. No post was needed

Comment: No worries I'll add an answer just in case others have similar issues.

Comment: By the way is it possible to be the same for edges by just changing the V to E? Since i tried and get different error. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main part of the query needs to be inside the `sideEffect` step. So something like...

```
g.inject(test).unfold().as("test").
  V(20704).as("v").
  sideEffect(select("test").
     unfold().as("kv").
     select("v").
     property(select("kv").by(Column.keys),
              select("kv").by(Column.values))).
  iterate()
```